# MPandroid x axis labels not aligning with bar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

My XAxis values are not aligning.  What setting should I modify?

[x axis not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os184.png)

Below is what I have in my code so far and .setLabelsToSkip won't work because I'm using version 3.0.1.

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setTextSize(15);
```

Here is my LabelFormatter class:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;

public class LabelFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
private final String[] mLabels;

public LabelFormatter(String[] labels) {
    mLabels = labels;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return mLabels[(int) value];
}
}
```

Here is my main activity setdata method:

```
    private void setData() {
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    String labels[]=new String[5];
    for (Cars c : values) {

       if (c.getX()==1){
            labels[0] = "Engine 1";
        }
        if (c.getX()==2){
            labels[1] = "Engine 2";
        }
        if (c.getX()==3){
            labels[2] = "Engine 3";
        }
        if (c.getX()==4){
            labels[3] = "Engine 4";
        }
        if (c.getX()==5){
            labels[4] = "Engine 5";
        }

        entries.add(new BarEntry((float) c.getX(), ((float) c.getY()),labels));

    }
    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null && mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(entries);

        mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
       //set1.setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(labels));
       //mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new BarValueFormatter(set1));
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(entries, "Engine Types");

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        set1.setColors(colors);


        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
        //mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelFormatter(labels));
        //mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new BarValueFormatter(set1));
        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextSize(50f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTypeface(mTfLight);



        mChart.setData(data);


    }

}
```

In my main activity I'm using it like this:

```
 mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
```

Comment: Where is your AxisValueFormatter? Please [edit] to include what you are using. Maybe `IndexValueFormatter`?

Comment: @David Rawson, I included the class file I'm using for LabelFormatter and how I'm calling it in my main activity.

Comment: So which one are you using? `IndexValueFormatter` or `LabelFormatter`? Your code shows both so it's not clear. Also, dont' use `(int) value` which will always floor the value. Use `int index = Math.round(value);`

Comment: I don't think I'm actually using that class.

Comment: Using IndexAxisValueFormatter, which comes with 3.0.1

Comment: I updated my main activity setdata method.

Comment: @raptor496 have you got the solution. If yes then please share it as I am also facing the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align xAxis label to the center of each bar, make setCenterAxisLabels property to false

```
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
```

Comment: I've tried that. What happens is that they do align, but the first label completely disappears off the screen and all label positions move to the left.  So the last bar doesn't have a label.

Comment: pls post tour (x,y) data

Comment: @raptor496 , have u find the solution for the issue which u mentioned ? am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Try setting the same property to true may work . xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom class for indexvalueformatter as follows and it should work

```
 public class FixedIndexAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
    private final float offset;
    private final String[]labels;

    public FixedIndexAxisValueFormatter(float offset, String[]labels) {
        this.offset = offset;
        this.labels = labels;
    }


    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        float x = value - offset;
        int index = Math.round(x);
        if (index < 0 || index >= labels.length || Math.abs(index - x) > 0.01f) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return labels[index];
        }
    }
}
```